# Group by month and add year and employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a simple table with every sale made in few past years. I would like to find out maximum sale per month and who made it and in which year and month.

**Table has following columns:**

> Id, date, amount, employeeId

I group data by **year(date)**, **month(date)**, employeeId and use **sum(amount)** to find sale of each employee in each month. Then I group further by **month(date)** and use max on **sum(amount)** column to find maximum sale per month. This is easy.

After that I would like to find out when exactly **(date)** and who exactly **(employeeId)** made that particular sale.

Comment: Table definitions, sample data and expected result, please. And you can also show us your query attempt.

Comment: And please also retag with the appropriate RDBMS (Sql Server, Oracle, MySql etc)

Answer (score 0):

Group data by year(date), month(date), employeeId and use sum(amount) to find sale of each employee in each month then order by sum(amount) desc. Your highest sellers will be at the top of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `rank()` function.  This may do what you want:

```
select s.*
from (select year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm, employeeid, sum(amount) as amount,
             rank() over (partition by year(date), month(date) 
                          order by sum(amount) desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from simpletable
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this like, if I understand correctly:

```
select top 1 with ties year(date), month(date), employeeId 
from TableName
group by year(date), month(date), employeeId
order by sum(amount) desc
```